# WPF Popup is closing immediately when using StaysOpen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, popup

I defined a popup:

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

where I bind `IsOpen` property of popup to `IsOpen` property in view model.

Setting it to `true` works as expected and it shows popup (when I step through the code when debugging). I set it to `true` in command event handler of a button, something like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OpenPopupCommand}" />
```

Command simply executes following code (it's in my view model):

```
IsOpen = true;
```

And now the weird thing:

right after opening the popup the breakpoint on `IsOpen` property setter is hit with the value `false`, which causes popup to close immediately.

That doesn't happen if I remove `StaysOpen="False"` (then it defaults to `True`).

It's like popup is showing, but it doesn't get/looses focus and it closes.

But I don't understand why?

Comment: Let me be sure I understasnd: You set a value to false, then wonder that it is set to false and is reacting to the value being set to false?

Comment: @Christopher No, I don't set it to `false`, that is the point - somewhere in "WPF system" it is set to false and it is due to `StaysOpen="False"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup.StaysOpen Property:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the Popup control closes when the control is no longer in focus.
>
> true if the Popup control closes when IsOpen property is set to false;
> false if the Popup control closes when a mouse or keyboard event occurs outside the Popup control. The default is true.

As you set this value to false it will close once "a mouse or keyboard event occurs outside the Popup control". With the miniscule, unavoidable mouse movements that humans make, you should get a "MouseMoved" Event instantly unless the mouse happens to be over the popup when it appars.

As you set `StaysOpen` to false, the value of `IsOpen` is also ignored.

Comment: Right... Didn't think of many events other from just clikcing outside the popup... Lesson to read carefully the docs :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn "Experience is wonderfull. Unfortunately you only ever get it *after* you would have needed it." - An old friend of mine.

Comment: Another, hopefully quick question: I have button on that popup, I have to click twice, to actually trigger its command. It's like popup is being focues and first I have to "unfocus" popup with one click, then I can click my button.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I know of a similar behavior with a Checkbox and one of the DataGrids. IIRC the DataGrid Element "eats" the Click Event, just getting the focus onto the Checkbox. I can not remember what the fix was off the top of my head. Better you ask a seperate question as this goes into WPF details I do not know right now.

Comment: Well, it truned out, that removing event handlers that handled focus events solved the issue, but I am quite unsure about it... I created fresh projct with popup and it worked as expected. Most probably yesterday I bloated my primary project with much "test code" that it started behaving weirdly... Thanks for support.